# svnrdump loading into existing svn

Tags: svn

I have created a dump file of an sub-directory in an old svn

svnrdump dump https://oldserver/svn/departmenta/projecta/test > testa.dump

i have a new svn repository with heaps of other projects already in it

```
svn/departmenta/...
    departmentb/...
    departmentc/...
```

if i load my testa.dump file like:

```
svnrdump load https://newserver/svn/departmenta/projecta/test < testa.dump
```

it actually restores it in the following location:

```
/svn/departmenta/projecta/test/departmenta/projecta/test
```

question:

if i load it like

```
svnrdump load https://newserver/svn/ < testa.dump
```

will it blow everything else away in the new repository ? or will it just end up in the right location:

/svn/departmenta/projecta/test

thanks,
tom

Comment: please state your svn repository layout.. I assume a single repository below /svn/?